# Synchronization across different systems

Tags: mysql, rest, architecture, synchronization, cpanel

I have 2 systems let's call them i and j. Each have it's own database.

Each have a registration page, where a user is inserted in a user table.

**What is the best way to synchronize both tables**, where if any user registers at system i it will be also registered at system j.

Notes:

1. I cannot read from each other databases directly.
2. I can do small changes in the code if needed and it will not affect the system performance or natural behavior.
3. I can create API's for both systems if needed.
4. I can add any tables or fields if needed.
5. I can create any cron jobs unless it will affect the performance of the system or server.
6. I'm using cPanel.

Technologies:

1. MySQL
2. PHP
3. REST API's

Comment: Why 2 systems?  Seriously, that seems to be causing more trouble than benefit.  Have you heard of "replication"?  "Clustering"?  "HA"?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that you list [cpanel](/questions/tagged/cpanel) as a technology shows you're working with an inflexible budget hosting vendor.  So it's unlikely they'll cooperate in setting up background tasks (cron jobs) to merge your user tables behind the scenes. (cpanel isn't a technology: it's a system administration user interface provided by hosting vendors who don't trust their customers' skills.)

So. you should design and implement a REST API in the code of both your apps to perform user registration and authentication tasks. You didn't show us the details of your app, so it's hard to design it for you. Still it seems likely you'll have to implement these operations:

- PUT user
- DELETE user
- GET user
- POST user to validate a user's password, etc. (Don't use GET to pass secret information: GET request parameters go into server logs.)
- PATCH to update details of a user.

If you get the API working, whenever you create/retrieve/update/delete user information in one app, you'll use the API to change it in the other.

Your best bet would be to create a third app just for user management, and have both your existing apps use it. That way you're sure to have one coherent source of truth about users. But you can do it just within two apps.

Comment: I only mentioned cPanel to let you know in case there is some functionality that can help me.

Regardless, they are both a simple register forms submit to a page and insert to database after validation.

In addition, I can create cron jobs. but I'm not sure what to do exactly.

I will edit my question accordingly.